# Should I notify answerers that the edited question's title makes their answers wrong?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

What should be done with question's title when after question's edition it asks about different thing than the title says, and already a few users had answered it's previous version?

Example:

The question ([Get selected option's text in an HTML select using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792045/get-selected-options-text-in-an-html-select-using-jquery/29792137#29792137)) is/was titled: ***Get selected option's text in an HTML select using jQuery***. The question is how to retrieve second options' texts from two separate selects. First the OP asks about selected second options (or the title + code suggest that), but after couple of answers with `option:selected` selector he clarifies that he wants those second options, not necessarily selected. So I edited my answer and it was OK. But now the title is wrong.

Now I could edit that to something like ***Get text of options with the same index, but in two separate divs with the same class name***. But when I edit that, and in the future somebody will find this question by its title, she/he might downvote those now "wrong" answers.

So my question is: should OP or I edit this title, and if so, will those answerers get notified? Or if they won't, should I notify them one by one in comments for them to prevent future downvotes? I can notify them, but it would be good if there was dedicated tool for that like a flag that the question's title/body was changed and then each answerer should get notification/comment for him to consider edition/deletion of her/his answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, the title was misleading since [the very first revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29792045/1). Title says "selected option" and question body says "second option". So answers dealing with the selected options were "wrong" from the get-go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, no you shouldn't notify the answerers.

What you should do is one or more of the following:

1. If the question was otherwise OK, roll back the edit. Editing a question, even the title, in such a way that it invalidates existing answers is not a nice thing to do.
2. However, if as ([Frédéric Hamidi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291072/should-i-notify-answerers-that-the-edited-questions-title-makes-their-answers-w/291074#comment180634_291072) points out) the title was wrong in in the first version then do nothing.
3. Possibly, flag the post for moderator attention using the "other" flag. We can then check to see if we can work out why the OP is doing this and take the appropriate steps to sort it out. Again this depends on the exact nature and extent of the edit.

Comment: I double checked and it was "selected" in the question, but it could just be for clarification as to which option OP wanted to get (in the code snippet this second option was selected). So it could be also answerers who misunderstood that and omitted the fact that OP was asking about the second one, not about only selected one. Some of them understood it from the beginning and used `:eq(1)` selector, and others were answering the title rather than the body of the question.